# How to generate a random number on page load?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to generate a random number when the page loads, but it doesn't seem to work for some reason. The random number just keeps on being generated every time the user presses the submit button and not only once from the beginning of the page load.

My HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
   <title> How many fingers </title>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"> </script>
 </head>

  <body>
   <h1> Test your luck </h1>
   <h2> How many fingers do I have?<h2>
   <input type="text" id="myGuess">
   <button id="button" onclick="check()"> submit </button>
</body>
</html>
```

My JavaScript:

```js
function loadNumber(){
   var myNumber = (Math.floor(Math.random()*10) +1);
 }
 //am not sure if the above function should generate the random number!
 window.onload = loadNumber;

function check(){

  var numberOfGuesses = (Math.floor(Math.random()*9)+1);
  var guess = document.getElementById("myGuess").value;
  var number = (Math.floor(Math.random()*10) +1);

  if(guess==number){
      alert("correct, it took you " + numberOfGuesses + " guesses to get it 
       right")
      document.location.reload();
   }else{
    numberOfGuesses++;
    alert("nope, try again!")
  }
}
```

Comment: how do you tell it wont work? Did you add console.log inside loadNumber() function

Comment: Well I mean... your code reads to generate a number every time the function is called...

Comment: Yes, it does create a new random number on page load, but it only stores it in the *local* variable `myNumber` which is subsequently disposed. On the other hand, the `check` function creates a new random `number` on every call as well that is actually used in the logic.

Comment: Yes you're absolutely right, it was a scope issue, the onload event occurs only within the function scope. I added the myNumber as a global variable along with the numberOfGuesses variable and it worked. Thanks Bergi!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The random number was changing, because you were generating a new random number every button click. Also the myNumber variable that you generate in loadNumber() was not available outside the function's scope and it was not used in the button's onClick function.

In the snippet below I transported the declaration of myNumber outside the function so that the both functions could access it and also constructed the guesses counter (with a starting value of 0)

```js
var myNumber;
var numberOfGuesses = 0;

function loadNumber() {
   myNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
}

function check() {
    numberOfGuesses++;
    var guess = document.getElementById("myGuess").value;
    if (guess == myNumber) {
        alert("correct, it took you " + numberOfGuesses + " guesses to get it right");
        document.location.reload();
    } else {
        alert("nope, try again!");
    }
}

loadNumber();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>How many fingers</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"> </script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Test your luck</h1>
    <h2>How many fingers do I have?<h2>
    <input type="text" id="myGuess">
    <button id="button" onclick="check()">submit</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I did the same as your above code except for two elements: 1- the numberOfGuesses var I made it equal to 1 instead of 0 as the user will have at least one try for the code to run, and 2- the numberOfGuesses++ is added in the else condition so it starts counting when the user gets it wrong, and now it's working perfectly. Many thanks Daniel!

Comment: Very happy to be able to help on stack overflow for once! If you could accept the answer it would make me extremely happy x

Answer (score 4):

I am very confused by your code really. So I restructured it to bring myNumber and numberOfGuesses outside of the functions, in order to broaden the scope. On page load it generates the random number in loadNumber() which is in the root scope here. Then check can access that and incriment guesses.

```
var myNumber;
var numberOfGuesses = 0;

function loadNumber(){
   myNumber = (Math.floor(Math.random()*10) +1);
}

function check(){
  numberOfGuesses++;

  var guess = document.getElementById("myGuess").value;

  if(guess==myNumber){
      alert("correct, it took you " + numberOfGuesses + " guesses to get it 
       right")
      document.location.reload();
   } else {
    alert("nope, try again!")
  }

}

window.onload = loadNumber;
```

Comment: Don't just post code. Explain what was wrong and how you fixed it.

Comment: Thanks a lot Wiplash. I did the same as your above code except for two elements: 1- the numberOfGuesses var I made it equal to 1 instead of 0 as the user will have at least one try for the code to run, and 2- the numberOfGuesses++ is added in the else condition so it starts counting when the user gets it wrong, and now it's working perfectly. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

On line 14 `document.location.reload();` you are reloading the page and recalling the random number function, hence regenerating a new number.

Comment: he only does that once the user guesses the correct number. The problem he's having is that a new random number is generated every time the user guesses.

Comment: That is correct Barmar. I just twisted the scope for the myNumber var and made it a global variable so the onload event doesn't occur exclusively within the loadNumber() function scope and now it's working.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var numberOfGuesses = (Math.floor(Math.random()*9)+1);
 var guess = document.getElementById("myGuess").value;
 var number = (Math.floor(Math.random()*10) +1);

 function check() {

  if(guess==number){
      alert("correct, it took you " + numberOfGuesses + " guesses to get it right")
   }else{
    numberOfGuesses++;
    alert("nope, try again!")
  }

}
```

Comment: Don't just post code. Explain what was wrong and how you fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Put `var myNumber = 0, numberOfGuesses = 0;` outside both functions so it is a global variable that can be accessed in both functions.

Inside check() you can increment the number of guesses by putting `numberOfGuesses++;` and compare against the global variable `myNumber` instead of `number`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the amazing support. Below is my final working code:

My Javascript:

```
var myNumber;
var numberOfGuesses = 1;

function loadNumber(){
  myNumber = (Math.floor(Math.random()*10) +1);
}

window.onload = loadNumber;

function check(){
  var guess = document.getElementById("myGuess").value;

  if(guess==myNumber){
     alert("correct, it took you " + numberOfGuesses + " guesses to get it 
      right")
     document.location.reload();
   } else {
     numberOfGuesses++;
     alert("nope, try again!")
   }

 }
```

My HTML:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
   <title> Guess Game </title>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"> </script>
 </head>

 <body>
    <h1> Test your luck </h1>
    <h2> How many fingers Am I holding up?<h2>
    <input type="text" id="myGuess">
    <button id="button" onclick="check()"> submit </button>
  </body>
</html>
```